# Building GRPC keeps failing on windows

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

I am trying build grpc CPP from the source using CMake as described in github for Windows but it is keep on failing with following error:

```
E:\gok\IEC61850\grpc\New folder\grpc>md .build

E:\gok\IEC61850\grpc\New folder\grpc>cd .build

E:\gok\IEC61850\grpc\New folder\grpc\.build>cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    The system cannot find the file specified

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/gok/IEC61850/grpc/New folder/grpc/.build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
```

Comment: Do you have a Visual Studio 2015 installation with a C++ plugin? Is your CMake recent enough to know how to fetch its configuration? Are you discovering the MSBuild.exe that comes with Visual Studio or another one?

Comment: You definitely have googled for the error message - "Failed to run MSBuild command" - and have checked [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478492/cmake-failed-to-run-msbuild-command-msbuild-exe) (or some other one), haven't you? Please, describe what have you tried to resolve the problem when following the answers to the existed questions.