# CMake: Failed to run MSBuild Command

Tags: cmake, msbuild

I'm trying to build Pangolin [1] from the command window, using

```
git clone https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin.git
cd Pangolin
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

However, the process fails at cmake .., where this error message appears:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Pangolin\build>cmake ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
    Switch: VCTargetsPath.vcxproj


  Exit code: 1
```

I saw that this might be connected to MSBuild not being in the path, so i added it to there. 
I also attempted running this from the various command terminals (also those of VS19).

Running this directly from CMake, rather than MSBuild was also attempted, and caused the same error message.

[1] https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin

Any idea what i might be missing?

PS: A comparable issue is treated in [CMake: failed to run MSBuild command: MSBuild.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478492/cmake-failed-to-run-msbuild-command-msbuild-exe), but none of the possible solutions seemed to help here.

Comment: This error did occur again trying to build parts of ORB_SLAM2 using 'cmake ..', so it does not seem to be a Pangolin specific issue