# Python setup.py error when running from cmd

Tags: python, setup.py

When I tried to build PyMesh from cmd by typing `setup.py build`, it says

```
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

When I tried with 'python setup.py build', it gives the following error, without any further information

```
error: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I've used 'where python' to verify that I only have one python installed from anaconda. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you try `python setup.py build`?

Comment: @DionSaputra yes I did, and it gave [WinError 193]

Comment: I don't know what setup.py is, but both of them seem to be suggesting a missing argument...

Comment: $1 in bash means the first argument of the program, so I'd assume the same for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

following [this issue](https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh/issues/103):

don't use setup.py, instead do as the following `cd thirdparty` and then run `python build.py all`
and then run `cmake`

Comment: When I ran cmake, it says "Failed to run MSBuild command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    The system cannot find the file specified" Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: install MSBuild.exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478492/cmake-failed-to-run-msbuild-command-msbuild-exe