# Error while installing PyPortfolioOps - qdldl_types - vscode - python

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I got an error in pip install PyPortfolioOps on VSCode

I have installed C++ components from VisualBuildTools, re-installed python and vscode

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for qdldl, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: qdldl, scs, osqp, ecos, cvxpy, PyPortfolioOpt
    Running setup.py install for qdldl ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\A.Emad\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0mgub_9p\\qdldl_6410923930ec4b9f9c018969d6cacaf3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\A.Emad\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0mgub_9p\\qdldl_6410923930ec4b9f9c018969d6cacaf3\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ho_kev_6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\qdldl'
         cwd: C:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0mgub_9p\qdldl_6410923930ec4b9f9c018969d6cacaf3\
    Complete output (31 lines):
    running install
    C:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_ext
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19044.
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (project):
      Failed to run MSBuild command:

        MSBuild.exe

      to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

        The system cannot find the file specified



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/A.Emad/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-0mgub_9p/qdldl_6410923930ec4b9f9c018969d6cacaf3/c/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".    The system cannot find the file specified
    CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: MSBuild.exe qdldlamd.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /v:m &&
    building 'qdldl' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cpp
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic -Ic\qdldl\include -IC:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -IC:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -IC:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcpp\qdldl.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\cpp\qdldl.obj -std=c++11
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
    qdldl.cpp
    c\qdldl/include/qdldl.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qdldl_types.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' 
failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\A.Emad\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0mgub_9p\\qdldl_6410923930ec4b9f9c018969d6cacaf3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\A.Emad\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0mgub_9p\\qdldl_6410923930ec4b9f9c018969d6cacaf3\\setup.py'"'"';f 
= getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ho_kev_6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\A.Emad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\qdldl' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am also cannot install
osqp==0.6.1
cvxpy

Can you please help

Comment: Have you checked other questions about the same error message ("Failed to run MSBuild command")? E.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478492/cmake-failed-to-run-msbuild-command-msbuild-exe).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `qdldl` does not support python3.10. Could you switch to another python version? Such as python3.9, python3.7.